# Xamarin.Forms Why so much space between two stacklayouts in PopUp view

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

[image]```

```
<pages:PopupPage.Resources>
        <local1:ChangeFrameBackgroudColor x:Key="ChangeFrameBackgroudColor" />
    </pages:PopupPage.Resources>

    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation DurationIn="400"
                                   DurationOut="300"
                                   EasingIn="SinOut"
                                   EasingOut="SinIn"
                                   HasBackgroundAnimation="True"
                                   PositionIn="Center"
                                   PositionOut="Center"
                                   ScaleIn="1.2"
                                   ScaleOut="0.8" />
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>

    <StackLayout Margin="12"

                 BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"
                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                 >
        <StackLayout>

            <ListView x:Name="list" HasUnevenRows="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding Firms}" SelectedItem="{Binding FirmId} " Header="{Binding}" ItemTapped="Choose_firm" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="0"  >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:ExtendedViewCell SelectedBackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"  >

                            <StackLayout  Padding="20, 10"  >
                                <Frame x:Name="frameLabel" BorderColor="#2188ff" BackgroundColor="{Binding IsActive, Converter={StaticResource ChangeFrameBackgroudColor}}" CornerRadius="10">
                                    <Label  FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="18" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Name}" ></Label>
                                </Frame>
                            </StackLayout>

                        </local:ExtendedViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentView BackgroundColor="#006BE6" >
                            <Label Margin="10" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Choose Firm"  TextColor="White" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        </ContentView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Label Text="Check Default:"  FontSize="18" />
                <CheckBox  IsChecked="False" Color="#006BE6" ></CheckBox>
            </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <Button Text="CHANGE"  BackgroundColor="#006BE6" IsEnabled="{Binding !IsBusy}" TextColor="White" Command="{Binding LoadFirmCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding FirmId}" CornerRadius="10"></Button>
            <Button Text="CANCEL"  BackgroundColor="Gray" IsEnabled="{Binding !IsBusy}" TextColor="White" Clicked="ClosePopUp" CornerRadius="10"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

</pages:PopupPage>
```

In first StackLayout i got ListView with only 3 elements. After that is lot empty space , and at the bottom of the PopUp are other two StackLayouts. I tried with Margins , Padding but nothing changed. I don't know what is the problem. Why is so much space. The bottom two StackLayouts dont have space between. How to solve this empty space?

Comment: please post a screenshot

Comment: i added , must hide some info but structure is this

Comment: Did you try adding Vertical Option to start to `ListView`. But I guess it would not consider it. Try setting a default `HeightRequest`

Comment: I dont know is HeightRequest a good practice?

Comment: I don't know how to organize my page in this situations when  a have components(in this case List can have from 0 to 10+ elements) with dynamic data

Comment: @Razzzz I search some info, have one solution, we have to set the Height of the list view according to the height of number of rows manually in code behind.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT and how to solve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not ran your code, but, looking at your XAML I can see that for your stack layout in the vertical option we tell it to end

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="End" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Label Text="Check Default:"  FontSize="18" />
                <CheckBox  IsChecked="False" Color="#006BE6" ></CheckBox>
```

However, Note how it is wrapped in the parent stack layout. Since it doesn't have a height request, it simply obeys what it was told to do. The parent stacklayout is the one where the list view is defined. So it loads the list view and then it renders the other stack layout at the bottom (End), does causing the massive gap
so in essence:

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="End" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Label Text="Check Default:"  FontSize="18" />
                <CheckBox  IsChecked="False" Color="#006BE6" ></CheckBox>
            </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
```

Goes To:

```
</StackLayout>
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="End" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Label Text="Check Default:"  FontSize="18" />
                <CheckBox  IsChecked="False" Color="#006BE6" ></CheckBox>
            </StackLayout>
```

Comment: I add HeightRequeired , and that fixed my problem, bad i don't know how will this affect on different screen sizes?